# Efficient way to implement this ActiveRecord Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using MySQL database and I have a datetime field inside it. In my rails application I have to fire a Query similar to the following,

```
MyTable.all(:conditions=>{my_date.to_date=>"2010-07-14"})
```

The my_date field is of datatype datetime. I should omit the time and should directly compare it with a date (but I am encountering an error near my_date.to_date due to obvious reasons). How to write an ActiveRecord Query for this scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyTable.all(:conditions=>["DATE_FORMAT(my_date, '%Y-%d-%m')=?", "2010-07-14"])
```

EDITED i think it should be

```
MyTable.all(:conditions=>["DATE_FORMAT(my_date, '%Y-%m-%d')=?", "2010-07-14"])
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer!! Yes its the second one.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient solution if you index the date column:

```
d = "2010-07-14".to_date
MyTable.all(:conditions=>["my_date BETWEEN ? AND ?", 
           d.beginning_of_day, d.end_of_day)
```